# Logout functionality from Redux store not working correctly, how do I distribute the reducer properly?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've created a redux store with the following functionalities,

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  currentUser: null,
  loading: false,
  error: false
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
   loginStart: (state) => {
       state.loading = true
   },
   loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
       state.loading = false
       state.currentUser = action.payload
   },
   loginFailure: (state) => {
    state.loading = false
    state.error = true
   },
   logout: (state) => {
    state.currentUser = null
    state.loading = false
    state.error = false
   },
   subscription: (state, action) => {
    if(state.currentUser.subscribedUsers.includes(action.payload)){
      state.currentUser.subscribedUsers.splice(state.currentUser.subscribedUsers.findIndex((channelId) => channelId === action.payload), 1)
    } else {
      state.currentUser.subscribedUsers.push(action.payload)
    }
   }
  },
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { loginFailure, loginSuccess, loginStart, subscription } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Next, Im trying to distribute the logout functionality but am unsure what Im doing wrong. below is the component im using it in

```
const {currentUser} = useSelector((state) => state.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const logout = () => {
    dispatch(logout(currentUser._id))
  }
```

And Im using it like this

```
<Button onClick={logout}>
          <LogoutIcon/>
          SIGN OUT
        </Button>
```

Comment: Please let me know if more information is needed to go about this, thank you.

Comment: Try this dispatch(logout())